# Reducir código y generar gráficos dinámicos

Tags: java

Actualmente estoy realizando el juego de N Reinas y a pesar de que eh logrado generar los gráficos que representan a las reinas. Mi problemática es que quiero agregar estas piezas de forma dinámica ya que dejare que el usuario seleccione la cantidad de reinas que desea colocar en el tablero, mi problema surge cuando le quiero agregar el método MouseDragged a cada pieza en el tablero pero el problema es que solo los eh podido agregar de forma manual y quisiera agregarlos de forma dinámica o saber si existe otra forma de hacer esto que quiero.

```
public class OtraPrueba extends JFrame {

    JPanel jpanel = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
    JLabel label[] = new JLabel[8];
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1);
    int N = 0, recX, recY;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OtraPrueba op = new OtraPrueba();
        op.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        op.setVisible(true);
        op.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public OtraPrueba() {
        jpanel.setLayout(null);
        jpanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
            label[i] = new JLabel();
            label[i].setBounds(25 + (50 * i), 25, 30, 30);
            label[i].setText("Q" + (i + 1));
            label[i].setBorder(border);
            label[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            jpanel.add(label[i], null);
        }

        label[0].addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                j1MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        label[1].addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                j2MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        label[2].addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                j3MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        label[3].addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                j4MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        label[4].addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                j5MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        label[5].addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                j6MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        label[6].addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                j7MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        label[7].addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                j8MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    public void j1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        label[0].setLocation(newPosition(evt)[0], newPosition(evt)[1]);
    }

    public void j2MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        label[1].setLocation(newPosition(evt)[0], newPosition(evt)[1]);
    }

    public void j3MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        label[2].setLocation(newPosition(evt)[0], newPosition(evt)[1]);
    }

    public void j4MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        label[3].setLocation(newPosition(evt)[0], newPosition(evt)[1]);
    }

    public void j5MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        label[4].setLocation(newPosition(evt)[0], newPosition(evt)[1]);
    }

    public void j6MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        label[5].setLocation(newPosition(evt)[0], newPosition(evt)[1]);
    }

    public void j7MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        label[6].setLocation(newPosition(evt)[0], newPosition(evt)[1]);
    }

    public void j8MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        label[7].setLocation(newPosition(evt)[0], newPosition(evt)[1]);
    }

    public int[] newPosition(MouseEvent evt) {
        int newX, newY;
        if (evt.getXOnScreen() <= 25) {
            newX = 25;
        } else if (evt.getXOnScreen() <= 75) {
            newX = 75;
        } else if (evt.getXOnScreen() <= 125) {
            newX = 125;
        } else if (evt.getXOnScreen() <= 175) {
            newX = 175;
        } else if (evt.getXOnScreen() <= 225) {
            newX = 225;
        } else if (evt.getXOnScreen() <= 275) {
            newX = 275;
        } else if (evt.getXOnScreen() <= 325) {
            newX = 325;
        } else if (evt.getXOnScreen() <= 375) {
            newX = 375;
        } else {
            newX = 375;
        }

        if (evt.getYOnScreen() <= 25) {
            newY = 25;
        } else if (evt.getYOnScreen() <= 75) {
            newY = 75;
        } else if (evt.getYOnScreen() <= 125) {
            newY = 125;
        } else if (evt.getYOnScreen() <= 175) {
            newY = 175;
        } else if (evt.getYOnScreen() <= 225) {
            newY = 225;
        } else if (evt.getYOnScreen() <= 275) {
            newY = 275;
        } else if (evt.getYOnScreen() <= 325) {
            newY = 325;
        } else if (evt.getYOnScreen() <= 375) {
            newY = 375;
        } else {
            newY = 375;
        }

        recX = newX;
        recY = newY;

        int retorno[] = {newX, newY};

        return retorno;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes, en un principio, aplicar cada listener dentro del ciclo de la misma manera como dinámicamente se van *seteando* la ubicación/tamaño, el texto, borde y alineación de cada `JLabel`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
  label[i] = new JLabel();
  label[i].setBounds(25 + (50 * i), 25, 30, 30);
  label[i].setText("Q" + (i + 1));
  label[i].setBorder(border);
  label[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
  label[i].addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
      myDraggingMethod(evt);//reemplaza a los metodos j1 j2 .... j8MouseDragged
    }
  });
  jpanel.add(label[i], null);
}
```

Luego de eso `mouseDragged` tendrá el método que recibe el argumento `MouseEvent`, pero aquí la diferencia es que solo será un único método para cualquier número de componentes y además de eso será capaz de identificar cual de esos componentes (*en este caso* `JLabel`) registró el evento de arrastre.

```
public void myDraggingMethod(MouseEvent evt) {
  if(evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
    ((JLabel)evt.getSource()).setLocation(newPosition(evt)[0],newPosition(evt)[1]);
  }
}
```

Con lo anterior le das de baja a un buen puñado de lineas de código.